# choose a certain amount of files in a directory randomly, and copy to some specific directories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

suppose there are 2000000 files in a directory, i.e. dir_source.

what I want is to choose 3 batches of 100 files randomly and copy them to 3 separate directories, i.e. dir_dist_1, dir_dist_2, dir_dist_3 , without repetition (each destination directory receives 100 distinct files).
anyone knows how to do that?
any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You have a wish here, posing as a question.

Comment: Use `shuf` to randomly shuffle the files, plus a Perl one-liner to move the files:
`find dir_source | shuf | head -n 300 | xargs -n 100 | perl -lne '$cmd = "mv $_ dir_dist_$."; print $cmd; system $cmd;'`

Answer (score 1):

I have something that could work, though I didn't try it on such a large scale

Also you need the `shuf` command for that, which shuffles input stream

```sh
#This will list all files and shuffle them, outputting the first 300 to shuffled_list.txt
ls | shuf -n 300 -o shuffled_list.txt

#Create the three directories
mkdir dir_dist_{1..3}

#Get the first 100 lines from shuffled_list.txt and cp them to dir_dist_1
sed -n '1,100p' < shuffled_list.txt | xargs -I % sh -c 'cp % dir_dist_1'
sed -n '101,200p' < shuffled_list.txt | xargs -I % sh -c 'cp % dir_dist_2'
sed -n '201,300p' < shuffled_list.txt | xargs -I % sh -c 'cp % dir_dist_3'
```

Answer (score 1):

List the files in the directory and shuffle the entries with shuf, printing only the 300 entries. Pipe the output through to awk

```
ls dir_source | shuf -n 300 | awk 'NR <= 100 { print $0" dir_dist_1" } NR > 100 && NR < 200 { print $0" dir_dist_2" } NR >= 200 { print $0" dir_dist_3" }' | xargs -I {} cp {} {}
```

Where the record number/line number is less that 100, print the file name ($0) and dir_dest_1, do the same for line numbers up to 200 (dir_dest_2) and then up to 300 (dir_dest_3).

Pipe the output through to xargs to run the copy command.